# replace values in a column separated by comma?

Tags: mysql, normalization

I have 2 tables. In *first table* there are 2 columns - `dept_id`, `stud_name`. Under there `stud_name` one row *has multiple student names separated by **","***.

and *2nd table*, there are 2 columns- `stud_id`, `stud_name`. each rows has one `stud_id` and one `stud_name`.

I want to replace 1st table's stud_name column by 2nd table's stud_id column. But when i use update query, rows with multiple values separated by comma has no replacement.

How to do that? Which query should i use to do this? please help.

thanks!

Comment: What query did you try (that didn't work on rows with multiple comma-separated values)? Did it work on rows without commas?

Comment: There really should be some sort of law against people designing database schemas, who know nothing about normalisation :-) You need to go back and re-engineer the schema; everything else is just adding warts to your pimples.

Comment: @paxdiablo The day in which MySQL guys create some kind of `join_with_multivalued_field` StackOverflow's questions will drop to half.

Comment: thanks for your replyes. I used UPDATE query.

UPDATE `table1` p
 INNER JOIN `table2` pp
 ON p.`stud_name` = pp.`stud_name`
 SET p.`stud_name` = pp.`stud_id`

it is working well with rows without commas. im very new in mysql. confused about re-engineer the schema. please help

Answer (score 1):

You have fundamental database structure issues here. Until you properly normalise the structure you are going to continue to have problems querying the data. You need to get to a solution which is more like:

#### First Table (Department)

- dept_id
- dept_name

#### Second Table (StudentDepartment)

- dept_id
- stud_id

#### Third Table (Student)

- stud_id
- stud_name

How easy this is will depend largely on the volume of data you have, for low volumes it might be easiest to re-key, for higher volumes you will need to look at a more automated solution.

Comment: Not sure why the font is so huge, if anyone can fix please do.

Comment: The "?" above the edit window will show you editing options such as headings etc.